# Are these two definitions of Bayesian Nash Equilibrium equivalent?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, bayesian-game

Consider a standard game $\Gamma$ with incomplete information. There are $n$ players indexed by $i=1,...,n$.
$S_i\equiv \{s_{i1},...,s_{iJ}\}$ is the set of actions of player $i$. $S\equiv \times_{i=1}^n S_i$. Each player $i$ is endowed with a type $\epsilon_i\equiv (\epsilon_{i1},..., \epsilon_{iJ})$ with distribution $f_i\in \Delta(E_i)$. $\{\epsilon_{i}\}_{i=1}^n$ are mutually independent. $\epsilon_i$ is player $i$'s private information. The utility of player $i$ from choosing $s_{ij}$ is $u_i(s_{ij}, s_{-i})+\epsilon_{ij}$. $u_i$ and $f_i$ are common knowledge for each $i$.

I want to define a Bayesian Nash Equilibrium (BNE) of $\Gamma$. I propose two definitions.

**Def 1:** Let $\sigma\equiv (\sigma_1,..., \sigma_n)$ where $\sigma_i:E_i\rightarrow \Delta(S_i)$ for each $i=1,...,n$. In particular, let $\sigma^{s_{ij}}_i(\epsilon_i)$ denote the probability that player $i$ plays action $s_{ij}$ when he is of type $\epsilon_i$, under $\sigma$. Then, $\sigma$ is a BNE if and only if
$$
s_{ij}\in argmax_{s_{ik}\in S_i} \sum_{s_{-i}\in S_{-i}} \int_{E_{-i}} [u_i(s_{ik}, s_{-i})+\epsilon_{ik}]\sigma^{s_{-i}}_{-i}(\epsilon_{-i})f_{-i}(\epsilon_{-i}) \text{ }d\epsilon_{-i}
$$
for each $j=1,..., J$ such that $\sigma^{s_{ij}}_{i}(\epsilon_{i})>0$, for each $\epsilon_i\in E_i$, and for each $i=1,...,n$.

**Def 2:** Let $\pi\equiv (\pi_1,..., \pi_n)\in \Delta(S)$. Let
$$
R_{ij}(\pi)\equiv \{\epsilon_i\in E_i: s_{ij}\in argmax_{s_{ik}\in S_i} \sum_{s_{-i}\in S_i}[u_i(s_{ik}, s_{-i})+\epsilon_{ik}]\pi_{-i}(s_{-i})\}
$$
$\pi$ is a BNE if and only if
$$
\pi_i(s_{ij})=\int_{R_{ij}(\pi)} f_i(\epsilon_i) d\epsilon_i
$$
for each $j=1,...,J$ and $i=1,...,I$.

**Clarification**: Def 2 comes from the fact that I've been taught at school that BNE is a fixed point. Hence, I'm trying to replicate a fixed point equation.

**Question 1**: In the case the "argmax" is always unique, are the two definitions equivalent? If yes/no, how do we show it?

**Question 2**: In the case the "argmax" may not be unique, are the two definitions equivalent? If yes/no, how do we show it?

Comment: If there are multiple argmax, I believe the definition does not work and the second definition would give you something different as well. In fact, 1 tries to define a BNE and 2 is trying to define an equilibrium outcome.

Comment: Thanks. Multiple argmax: I have replaced $=$ with $\in$. At school, I have been taught that BNE is a fixed point. This is what I'm trying to replicate in 2, a fixed point equation. If 2 is wrong, could you tell me where do we get this fixed point equation?

Comment: Say $s_{ij},s_{ik}\in\arg\max$. It's not necessary that both $s_{ij}$ and $s_{ik}$ be played with positive probability in a BNE. But your Def 2 seems to suggest that they must.

Comment: Thanks. Can we distinguish the answer in two cases (armax unique versus argmax not unique)? See edited question.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly $R_{ij}(\pi)$ is supposed to be in your second definition. If you want a definition via fixed points, you could define something like $BR(\sigma)=\{\sigma'\mid \forall i,\epsilon_i:\: \sigma_i'(\epsilon_i) \text{ is a best response against } \sigma_{-i}\}$. A BNE is then a fixed point of the correspondence $BR$.